# Define state interface of functional component in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

With hooks the functional React component is no more a stateless component. It can have state so it makes sense to define state interface for functional component.

Although typescript doesn't throw any error/warning on that but it would be good to define that.

Need help in doing the same.

Comment: You can specify the state shape when using hook. Could you add a specific example of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using hooks, state is not store in the component, but rather somewhere in the context of component and that context ca be accessed in component. When you look into signature of useState hook it says:

```js
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];
```

So that means your state is infered from its initial values. If you want to be super explicit you can pass the generic to that function:

```js
const [s, setS] = useState<{stateShape: StateShape}>({});
```

But as i said.. Component is still stateless because state is not stored in component.